# How certain do I need to be that my Yom Kippur shoes are leather-free?

Tags: halacha, clothing, yom-kippur, tisha-bav, inuy-affliction

Okay, no leather shoes for Yom Kippur (or Tisha B'Av).  I always assumed if the label said `ALL MAN MADE MATERIALS` or `100% CANVAS` or something like that, that we could trust the label.  (Would they really sneak leather in?  It's more expensive, right?)

What is the Halachic standard for how certain I need to be that a pair of shoes is actually leather-free, particularly with today's complex market for manufactured shoes? Is there Halachic literature on this, or can you report any verbal response you've received on it?

Comment: If you're REALLY not sure what you should wear, see http://yomkippurshoes.com/tag/featured/page/2/. They'll figure it out for you, or, maybe, confuse you. Everything has a price!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for Chalov AKum I would Imagine It works Here too.

Comment: Certainly the logic of "trust in economics and regulation" would apply here; R' Moshe's heter for milk goes beyond that, that "knowing" counts as "seeing" with regards to the enactment on milk.  For general kashrus, "knowing" is enough.  So if we can apply a kal vachomer from food kashrus (and I'm correct on the metzius), should be fine.

Comment: @Shalom Just to correct a misconception R' Moshe's heter for milk is not based on that, it was based on the government testing that was done on milk. These days the testing is not done, so those who drunk Chalov Akum are not relying on him, but rather on later opinions. http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/rav_moshe_ztls_heter_of_cholov_stam_revisited/

Comment: @Ariel let's just say it's more complicated than that. R' Moshe has a series of responsa about the subject, and interpreting them is still being fought over today.